# How to Separate Data Column in R

Tags: r, formatting

I have data structured 4464 in rows, and 1 column. 
Data should be in 4464 in rows and 8 columns.

Data contains:
Each file has a two
line header, followed by data.The columns are:  julian day, ten minute
interval marker, temperature, pressure, wind speed, and wind direction.  The
ten minute interval marker is a number between 1 and 144 representing time.
data comes from [here](ftp://amrc.ssec.wisc.edu/pub/aws/10min/rdr/2013/089000113.r)

There are total of 12 data files like this, and my goal is put them in one 3D array.
But I am stuck to fix this data form.

Example of Data

```
Jan  13   Station : 8900  Harry               
  Lat : 83.00S  Long : 121.40W  Elev :  957 M
    1    1   -7.8  879.0    5.6  360.0  444.0    9.1
    1    2   -7.9  879.1    4.6  360.0  444.0    9.1
    1    3   -7.6  879.2    4.1  345.0  444.0    9.1
    1    4   -7.6  879.3    4.1  339.0  444.0    9.1
    1    5   -7.6  879.4    4.8  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    6   -7.9  879.4    3.6  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    7   -8.0  879.3    4.6  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    8   -8.0  879.4    4.1  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    9   -8.2  879.4    5.8  338.0  444.0    9.1
    1   10   -8.4  879.5    4.6  339.0  444.0    9.1
```

I tried and researched few things, but I don't know what the best way is.

My code was (Could not code with data.frame...):

```
 setwd("/Users/Gizmo/Documents/Henry")
  dir()
  h13<-dir()
  henry<-read.csv(h13[1],skip=2,header=FALSE)
  colnames(c("J-Day","MinInter","Temp","Pressure","WindSpeed","WindDir","Ext1","Ext2"))
```

I looked at other questions, and guide and data.frame seems like the best way, but I could not code. (Ended up with data dimension NULL.)

Please give me advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: Is that exactly what your data file looks like? If so, you want `read.table`, not `read.csv`.

Comment: Oh CSV is comma separated isn't it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be using `read.csv` instead of `read.table`:

```
henry <- read.table(text='Jan  13   Station : 8900  Harry               
  Lat : 83.00S  Long : 121.40W  Elev :  957 M
    1    1   -7.8  879.0    5.6  360.0  444.0    9.1
    1    2   -7.9  879.1    4.6  360.0  444.0    9.1
    1    3   -7.6  879.2    4.1  345.0  444.0    9.1
    1    4   -7.6  879.3    4.1  339.0  444.0    9.1
    1    5   -7.6  879.4    4.8  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    6   -7.9  879.4    3.6  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    7   -8.0  879.3    4.6  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    8   -8.0  879.4    4.1  340.0  444.0    9.1
    1    9   -8.2  879.4    5.8  338.0  444.0    9.1
    1   10   -8.4  879.5    4.6  339.0  444.0    9.1', header=FALSE, skip=2)
names(henry) <- c("J-Day","MinInter","Temp","Pressure","WindSpeed","WindDir","Ext1","Ext2")
```

Result:

```
> henry
   J-Day MinInter Temp Pressure WindSpeed WindDir Ext1 Ext2
1      1        1 -7.8    879.0       5.6     360  444  9.1
2      1        2 -7.9    879.1       4.6     360  444  9.1
3      1        3 -7.6    879.2       4.1     345  444  9.1
4      1        4 -7.6    879.3       4.1     339  444  9.1
5      1        5 -7.6    879.4       4.8     340  444  9.1
6      1        6 -7.9    879.4       3.6     340  444  9.1
7      1        7 -8.0    879.3       4.6     340  444  9.1
8      1        8 -8.0    879.4       4.1     340  444  9.1
9      1        9 -8.2    879.4       5.8     338  444  9.1
10     1       10 -8.4    879.5       4.6     339  444  9.1

> str(henry)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ J-Day    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ MinInter : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Temp     : num  -7.8 -7.9 -7.6 -7.6 -7.6 -7.9 -8 -8 -8.2 -8.4
 $ Pressure : num  879 879 879 879 879 ...
 $ WindSpeed: num  5.6 4.6 4.1 4.1 4.8 3.6 4.6 4.1 5.8 4.6
 $ WindDir  : num  360 360 345 339 340 340 340 340 338 339
 $ Ext1     : num  444 444 444 444 444 444 444 444 444 444
 $ Ext2     : num  9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1 9.1
```